# height of the pdf using itextsharp

Tags: itext

how to get the page size of the pdf using iTextsharp? i am using Pdf reader to number of pages for getting PDF . please Provide code for calculating the Size of the pdf

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [webified iTextSharp example](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx) [PageInformation.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=PageInformation) corresponding to [PageInformation.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=107) from [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) which outputs multiple bits of information about a document using iTextSharp. The central method is this:

```
public static void Inspect(StringBuilder sb, byte[] pdf, string fileName) {
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
  sb.Append(fileName);
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  sb.Append("Number of pages: ");
  sb.Append(reader.NumberOfPages);
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  Rectangle mediabox = reader.GetPageSize(1);
  sb.Append("Size of page 1: [");
  sb.Append(mediabox.Left);
  sb.Append(',');
  sb.Append(mediabox.Bottom);
  sb.Append(',');
  sb.Append(mediabox.Right);
  sb.Append(',');
  sb.Append(mediabox.Top);
  sb.Append("]");
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  sb.Append("Rotation of page 1: ");
  sb.Append(reader.GetPageRotation(1));
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  sb.Append("Page size with rotation of page 1: ");
  sb.Append(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  sb.Append("Is rebuilt? ");
  sb.Append(reader.IsRebuilt().ToString());
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  sb.Append("Is encrypted? ");
  sb.Append(reader.IsEncrypted().ToString());
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```